# histogram in matlab with huge input

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a histogram in matlab. My data size is huge (3.5 million), x and y data are the same size (both are 3.5 million)

My original data has 200,200,88 3D matrix, I reshaped it to 1 column 
the code for this:

```
[dose , size] = Dose('C:\R1')
s = size(1)*size(2).size(3)
t = reshape(dose, s, [])
```

When I try the command hist(t), I got a 1 bar only.

My workspace is as the following:

```
dose   <200x200x88 double>
s      3520000
size   [200,200,88]
t      <3520000x1 double>
```

Could you tell me how to make a histogram with this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a single long vector from your 3D array you can use just the `(:)` operator. Try the following code:

> > num_of_bins = 100 ; %change to whatever # you want
> >     hist(dose(:),linspace(min(dose(:)),max(dose(:)),num_of_bins));

The `hist` will take only the relevant limits of `dose` (min to max) and you can control the # of bins at will. I've used `linspace` to create a linearly spaced bin vector, but this can be modified also to a different set of bins by assigning a different range vector.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to generate a vector of size 3520000x1 and build a histogram with it.

> > val=rand(3520000,1);
> >
> > hist(val)

It's possible your data has a few singular outliers causing your bins to look something like (1,0,0,...,3519999).
If you save your histogram bins like `h=hist(data);` you can see what happened.